# d3 vs. svg When Dealing with Element

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Is there a preference between using

```
d3.selectAll()
```

and

```
svg.selectAll()
```

when

```
var svg = d3.select("#someChart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);
```

when dealing with(creating, removing) elements in the svg tag?

Comment: d3.selectAll('#svg'); is selecting the every element with id 'SVG'. whereas svg.selectAll('#svg'); is selecting every 'svg' element thats a child of the 'SVG' element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AJ_91 pointed out, `d3.selectAll(...)` searches the entire document, whereas `svg.selectAll(...)` limits the search to the SVG in the selection. The latter is expectedly more performant for large documents.

However, there's another important difference: If the var `svg` references a d3 selection that contains more than a single  element then a subselection like `svg.selectAll('path')` will select all `<path>`s within each `<svg>` as expected, but the resulting selection will also maintain "awareness" of the "cousin" relationship between `<path>`s that have different `<svg>` parents.

This is called nested selections as bostock [explains here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/). Nested selections are used for constructing tables, since tables imply a 2-level hierarchy (*n* rows then *m* columns per row). The nested-svg-selection analog to tables would be if you have a multi-level dataset from which you wanted to create multiple SVG's, each of which contains multiple trendline paths (or multiple barchart `<rect>`s, etc).

Comment: Is it true that I should use svg whenever possible, instead of d3?

Comment: Yeah, if that `svg` selection contains the right stuff then I can't think of a reason not to. It's more efficient. Of course just be mindful in case there are multiple svgs in that selection and you only want to address a single one of them.